# How to put an article before a word in a phrase if the first word is uncountable and the second word is countable?

Tags: usage, indefinite-article, noun-phrases

> Clinimetrics corner: the many faces of "selection bias"

Now, selection and bias are both nouns.
Selection is an uncountable noun and a countable noun.
Bias is a countable noun.
So, can I put "a" before "selection" on the basis of that it is uncountable? Or I will put it on the basis of the second word, bias?
(selection) or the second one (bias).
Link: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3101070/

Another thing I want to ask is that if there is a noun phrase containg two words, does the selection of an article depend on the first word of the noun phrase?

Comment: The fact that "selection" is an uncountable noun *in other contexts* is irrelevant here, where it simply functions as an "adjective" modifying the "head noun" ***bias***. And that "adjective" might not be present in the first place, so ask yourself if you'd be prepared to write "...the many faces of **a bias**" (I wouldn't, but I don't really understand what you're trying to say, anyway),

Comment: ...but I could talk about *the many uses of a jug*, OR *the many uses of **a water jug***, which looks to me like another "uncountable noun and a countable noun" pairing on a par with yours.

Comment: My favourite "selection bias" example at the moment: [Why are iron levels different in the left and right hands?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/32541/why-are-iron-levels-different-in-the-left-and-right-hands/32542?noredirect=1#comment63602_32542)

Comment: @AryenduKumar Please provide an example sentence.

Comment: After reading the summary at the link, I see that there are over 40 subtypes of selection bias.  Type #33 of selection bias, or type #17, or whatever name has been applied to them, could be called "a selection bias" but I think it would be clearer (and more idiomatic) to say "... is a type of selection bias".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I just had to ask that if there is a noun phrase (which may have two or more words), then, the selection of article depends on the first word?

Comment: AryenduKumar: No - in general, it's the *second* word (the "head noun") that counts. So it's *the many uses of **a** water jug* in the singular, or *the many uses of water **jugs*** in the plural (plural nouns get the "zero article", so no *"**a**"* there).

Comment: ...note that the cited text in your question isn't an English sentence - it's just *the title of an academic paper*. In that context, the phrasing is perfectly natural - but if you're asking about some particular construction, we really need to see it in the context of a (real, or made-up) ***sentence.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers can I say that, water is uncountable and jug is countable (singular too), so, it is due to "jug' and not "water" "A" is used in your first example ?

Comment: Yes. As a rule, if you see two "consecutive nouns", most likely the first is being used adjectivally (the first word in "**car radio**" is an "adjective", not a noun). So anything you know about countable/uncountable or singular/plural nouns applies to the second word, ***not*** the first.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, off topic, but I love the hæmoglobin anecdote. A wonderful cautionary tale for careful reasoning.

Comment: To be pedantic, [bias is both countable and uncountable](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bias).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, one more question is that if I put 'the' before selection bias', then, what is the meaning from that, is it a particular bias that is selection or a particular type of selection ?

Comment: It's not relevant whether you precede the compound noun by 'the' or 'a' (or the 'zero article' with the plural form ***selection biases***). In all cases, the word ***selection*** functions as an adjective, identifying a particular type of bias / biases.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, if in a pair of consequtive nouns, "the" is written before the first word, like "The" car radio, "the" is telling about a specific car or a specific radio ?

Comment: I don't understand why you keep asking about *a **pair** of consecutive **nouns***. It makes no difference whether a "noun phrase" is a single word, adjective + noun, "noun used adjectivally" + noun, or any other string of words that functions as a noun phrase. As a general principle, using "the" before ***any*** noun phrase means it's referring to a ***specific*** instance of whatever that noun phrase represents. The fact that the first word in "car radio" or "selection bias" could in other contexts be used as a noun is irrelevant when it's actually being used as an adjective, as here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selection bias is a compound noun. For compound nouns that are made up only of nouns, only the final noun is ever pluralised, so you can have egg sandwiches, but you can't have eggs sandwich.

The countability of a compound noun is therefore based only on the final noun.

In your example, [bias](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bias) is the final word, and it is normally countable (though, as the link I provided shows, it can also be uncountable), so you can have selection biases or a selection bias.

Comment: Bias is countable but can I also have no article before 'selection bias' ? Will the justification be - It will give a general meaning.

Comment: @AryenduKumar my bad, I didn't consider the uncountable usage. Yes, It would relate to bias in general.

Comment: @Then, Mnay time I have seen that sentences like above, second word is singular and countable. and the first word is uncountable and as per the rule there should be 'a' or 'an' but there is no article ... Why ?

Comment: can you provide examples?

Comment: Do not remeber, please explain from the context of "selection bias"

Comment: @AryenduKumar the explanation for "selection bias" is that bias can also be uncountable.